# When exporting as pdf a layer that should not be transparent becomes transparent

Tags: inkscape, pdf, transparency

I am making an image by pasting a pdf image on a background. Everything looks great in Inkscape, but when exporting the entire Inkscape file to pdf, the pdf image gets somewhat transparent for no reason.

Attached you will find two files that show my issue. The Inkscape svg shows how it is supposed to be, but when I export, and then choose pdf, the top layer gets transparent. I have tried to make the popup opaque, but haven't been able to find a way. I have updated to v0.92.2 and removed any empty layers.

Do anyone have any tips as to how I can export as pdf and make the pdf look like the svg?

[Link to File Folder](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtHrripAcYVugUxYN9X3Bi-0EEm3?e=t6Hnrl)

Answer (score 1):

You have two layers that are apparently identical, as well as one layer that is empty, at least from what I've been able to determine. The program I use, v0.92 informed me that your file was created in an older version. I don't think that's a factor, but I suspect the extraneous layers may be the key.

Consider to remove or disable the duplicated layer and to remove the apparently empty one as well.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help. I tried to remove the duplicated layers, but that did unfortunately not help. Will try to update to the newest version now to see if that does the trick. Were you able to export it correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately updating did not help either.

Answer (score 1):

I may be too late to the party, since this question was posted a while ago, but I hate to see an unresolved question. Anyway, there seem to be lots of nested groups in your document, at least 4 or 5 levels, which can be problematic in some cases.

You can fix it by selecting all, and then click *Extensions > Arrange > Deep ungroup*

Now save the PDF.

I tried this using Inkscape 0.92, and it appears to resolve the problem. Here's a screenshot showing the fixed PDF in Adobe Reader

[image]

Also note there's no need to have everything on separate layers in Inskcape, although it's not what's causing the problem in this particular case, it can cause problems in some cases. You can arrange objects in the stack using the buttons on the Control Bar when using the Select and Transform Objects tool (F1).

[image]

Layers do have their uses in Inkscape, especially for example if you want to lock a layer, or have layer names for other processes. Otherwise, it's probably best not to use them unless you really have to.